# Point to Neo4J graph data on another drive

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to set up Neo4J Desktop and hook up an existing graph which was previously running on Community Edition. I've created a new Project and a new local graph but I haven't managed to hook it up to the existing data files.

The graph's data is located on a separate drive (M:) at the root, with the following structure:

[image: graph folder data structure]

I've been playing around with the `dbms.directories.*` settings but I can't seem to get it to handle this structure. It seems to always be expecting something like `databases/graph.db/**`.

Is it possible to set it up so I keep the data as it is on the M: drive, or do I need to restructure the folders?

Comment: I would go with restructuring folders and keep it simple

Comment: Are you getting an error after setting path to M drive?

Answer (score 1):

@Stuart

I never tried using **`dbms.directories.*`**. 
But I have used for looking data folder and successfully set data folder location on other drive using following conf:

```
dbms.directories.data=P:/Neo4jDB/
```

You can try setting Paths of other directories (plugins, logs etc) in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I mentioned `dbms.directories.*` I meant `dbms.directories.data`, `dbms.directories.plugins` etc etc rather than using a "*". From the KB article here (https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-define-my-graphdb-at-a-path-other-than-under-neo4j-home-for-windows/) that suggests it will looks for a `databases` folder in "P:/Neo4jDB/" rather than that pointing to the databases actual files. Does that make sense?

Comment: In the end the client was happy to reorganise the folders and go with the standard, out-the-box structure so I avoided the whole problem in the end. However, your approach was useful during my experimentation, thanks!